# RSPEC, DRY a test with 100s of use cases

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, rspec2

in rspec, I have a spec that looks something like this:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe IncomingMailsController do

  include Devise::TestHelpers

  it "should find the correct text in the sample" do
  sample_text = '100s of these'
  target_text = 'find me'
   .... ALL Kinds of stuff to process (30+ lines)
   thread.content.should == 'find me'
  end

end
```

Is there a way with rspec, to allow me to somehow use all that logic in one block? And then create 100s of it "xxxxx" do, and pass that a variable being the sample text?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can put the `it` test blocks inside a loop, and run through a collection of all the times you want to each for (in the example below those items are in the `search_items` collection)

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe IncomingMailsController do

  include Devise::TestHelpers

  search_items.each do |item|
    it "should find the correct text (#{item}) in the sample" do
      sample_text = '100s of these'
      target_text = item
      .... ALL Kinds of stuff to process (30+ lines)
      thread.content.should == 'find me'
    end
  end

end
```

**UPDATE**

I saw on a comment to another answer in this threase that you have a directory with 100+ files of samples, you can get the list of filenames using [Dir#glob](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Dir.html#M000629). You can then use that in the loop to  generate your `it` test cases.

**UPDATE 2**

```
  Dir.glob('/path/to/files/*.txt').each do |file_name|
    it "should find the correct text in the sample #{file_name}" do
      file_content = File.open(file_name, "rb")
      sample_text = '100s of these'
      target_text = 'fine me'
      .... ALL Kinds of stuff to process (30+ lines)
      thread.content.should == 'find me'
    end
  end
```

You might have to play with the full path of file_name but that should get you some of the way.

Comment: Thanks ctcherry, the collection is a large directory of files. so I don't know if this would work?

Comment: Is creating a helper possible? And I can make 100 if blocks, which are specific to scenarios, and then use a helper inside?

Comment: I think we might need to see more code. It's hard to know which part you are trying to DRY up. Is the result of processing all of the files the same? Or are you checking for something different for each one?

Comment: The result of each of the files is the same "find me". Its for processing emails, so there is a lot of logic to find that "find me" and I think it would be good to have a "it XXXX do for each file as it refers to an email client. Which is why I was wondering about using a helper?

Comment: I definitely agree with having an `it` block for each test case, then if one fails, you know exactly what you need to look at.

Comment: I suggest you look into Ben Mabey's email_spec to absorb some of the grief of looking through the email (https://github.com/bmabey/email-spec).

Comment: @Steve thanks but that's for sending emails, I'm processing incoming emails. Any docs on how to create a helper for a rspec?

Comment: Directly addressing the question: A helper is just a block of code. Stick it in your file or in spec_helper.rb and you can call it at will. I often do def setup_blah_blah; @foo = Foo.new; end. However, you might also consider a before block, as it is run before each example.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is what you're looking for, but how about:

```
['xxxxxx', 'yyyyyyy', 'zzzzzzzz'].each do |thing|
  it "finds #{thing} in the sample do
    # and so on...
  end
end
```

Naturally, you might opt for something other than an array for storing your test strings, but this should get you started.

Comment: Thanks Steve. Not sure if that will work. I created a dir of samples, which has 100+ text files. Each text file when processed should return "find me". To get to that point it requires a lot of code which I want to DRY. So I was wondering if there was a way to DRY with a helper in RSPEC? Or perhaps itterage over all the files in one description? IDK? just learning all this rpsec stuff now thxs